# Servlet path info includes empty string

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, url-mapping

I have the following servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/publication/topic/*")
public class ViewTopicPublicationsServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String[] pathInfo = request.getPathInfo().split("/");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pathInfo));
        ...
    }
}
```

And for example if I have such url:
`http://localhost:8080/bulletinboard/publication/topic/SALE`

I want to omit empty string. So `pathInfo` resulted in `[SALE]` instead of `[,SALE]`

How this may be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the first character since it's always a slash:

```
request.getPathInfo().substring(1).split("/")
```